# $|Gal(f(x),\mathbb Q )|$?

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $f(x) = x^5 -7$ then i need to find $|Gal(f(x),\mathbb Q )|$,
I can use Eisenstein to see that $f(x)$ is irreductible but the order isn't $5$, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $f(x)$ roots are: $$\sqrt[5]{7},\;\omega\sqrt[5]{7},\;\omega^2\sqrt[5]{7},\;\omega^3\sqrt[5]{7},\;\omega^4\sqrt[5]{7},$$
where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi}{5}i}$.

Let $\Sigma$ the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then
\begin{equation}
\Sigma=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7},\omega).
\end{equation}

From the tower theorem we have
\begin{equation}
[\Sigma:\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7},\omega):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7})]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7}):\mathbb{Q}].
\end{equation}
We observe that $\text{irr}(\sqrt[5]{7},\mathbb{Q})=x^5-7$, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7}):\mathbb{Q}]=5$.

Then
\begin{equation}
[\Sigma:\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7},\omega):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7})]\cdot 5.
\end{equation}
We are looking for $\text{irr}(\omega,\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7}))$, we observe that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7},\omega)\ne\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7})$, because every element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7})$ is real, while $\omega$ is a complex number.

Now, $\text{irr}(\omega,\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7}))=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, then 
\begin{equation}
|Gal(\Sigma:\mathbb{Q})|=[\Sigma:\mathbb{Q}]=20.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

The splitting field contains **all** fifth roots of $7$, so all
of $\exp(2\pi ik/5)\sqrt[5]7$. The $\exp(2\pi ik/5)$ generate a cyclotomic
field of degree $4$. It follows that the splitting field has degree $20$
and so the Galois group has order $20$. By studying the action of
the elements of the Galois group on $\sqrt[5]7$ and $\exp(2\pi i/5)$
it's possible to elucidate its structure.

Comment: So it's kinda like when you add the roots of $5$ you get the exp, and this will generate the cyclotomic field that "Will come along"